# Unable to share values between processes in Multiprocessing python

Tags: python, python-import, python-multiprocessing

I tried to run two scripts using multiprocessing as follows:

```
import multiprocessing
files=["file1","file2"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for name in files:
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: __import__(name))
        process.start()
```

I'm not able to pass the arguments while initiating the process because I get the error as
***lambda function accepts 0 arguments, but 2 were given***.

I need to share a variable's data between the scripts. Any suggestions on how to resolve this.

> **Note:** The functions in scripts were not able to run when the functions are imported and executed in multiprocessing. Hence I choose
> this approach.

Comment: what are the files here and what you want to do with lambda?

Comment: @Bipulsinghkashyap files are the python scripts' names.  When i'm initialising process as multiprocessing.Process(target=file1.py,args=(a,b))   im getting errors in my script as it has some publishing and subscribing operations.    Hence with this approach im able to get the script running without errors.    But now with this approach, i cant pass any arguments specifically.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the function name as a target, not the file.

```
# Importing functions

from service.file import get_service 
from service.file2 import get_another

from multiprocessing import process


def run_in_parallel(functions:list):
    proc = []
    for fn in fns:
        p = Process(target=fn, args=(data))
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)

if __name__=='__main__':
    func = [get_service, get_another]
    run_in_parallel(func)
```

create a list of a process named `proc` here, starting process one by one and inserting it into proc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my issue is that when i import the functions and start it as described above, ( one of the script has publish and subscribe operations to cloud server) the script always returns an error named publish timed out. But when i run with file as target, it is running without any errors.  That's been the issue faced by me .With file as target i'm not able to pas any arguments. With functions as target, script is throwing errors.